# Mongo query to push a value to an array, which itself is an element of another array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a Mongo doc, that looks like this -

```
{
  "type": "TYPE",
  ...
  "big_array": [
    "simple_element1",
    "simple_element2",
    ....
    {
      "object_element": [
        "one", "two"
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is add an element to `object_element`, so that it becomes

```
{
  "object_element": [
    "one", "two", "three"
  ]
}
```

I'm looking for a single query that could do this.

Thanks in advance!

---

*EDIT:*

- *To be clear, I cannot be sure about the position of `object_element` inside `big_array`.*
- *There will be only a single occurrence of `{ "object_element" ... }` in `big_array`.*

Answer (score 0):

*Solved the problem immediately after posting the question here*

The query is this --

```
db.collectionName.update({
  "type": "TYPE",
  "big_array.object_element": [
    "one",
    "two"
  ]
},
{
  $push: {
    "big_array.$.object_element": "three"
  }
});
```

What I missed when I tried earlier was including the `big_array.object_element` in the query section.